# Output only parts from a logfile (a function name and a param value of it)

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, logfiles

I dont have find a question like for this specific case, I have a logfile like this:

```
"foo function1 para1=abc para2=def para3=ghi bar 
foo function2 para1=jkl para2=mno para3=pqr bar"
```

Now i want execute a one-liner on a gnu bash with this output:

```
function1 def
function2 mno
```

`foo` indicates the start for the function name and `bar` is the sign for the end of this block. So i want to search for the word "foo", extract the next word (the function name) and then search for the param2 and extract only the value.

How can I do this with a one-liner (not a script)?

Comment: in log file, is there a line break between bar and foo?

Comment: not between foo and bar, but between the next foo - bar block

Comment: Are there really double quotes at the start and end of your input file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Simi: Try:

```
awk -F'[ ="]' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i=="foo"){printf("%s",$(i+1))};if($i=="para2"){printf(" %s\n",$(i+1))}}}'  Input_file
```

Here I am making field separator as space or = or ("), then I am traversing into all the fields of a line then searching for strings(foo,para2) if any field has these values then simply printing the next field's values as per your requirement. Let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

If this isn't all you need:

```
$ awk -F'[ =]' '{print $2, $6}' file
function1 def
function2 mno
```

then edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide more meaningful and truly representative sample input/output.

Answer (score 1):

**Perl One Liner**

```
perl -lane 'print "$F[1] ",(split(/=/,$F[3]))[1]' logfile
```

**Input**

```
"foo function1 para1=abc para2=def para3=ghi bar  
foo function2 para1=jkl para2=mno para3=pqr bar"
```

**Output**

```
function1 def  
function2 mno
```

Answer (score 0):

> `foo` indicates the start for the function name and bar is the sign for
>   the end of this block. So i want to search for the word "foo", extract
>   the next word (the function name) and then search for the param2 and
>   extract only the value.

**With some assumption, if your log file would look like below then**

**Either**

```
$ cat mylog
foo function1 para1=abc para2=def para3=ghi bar foo function2 para1=jkl para2=mno para3=pqr bar
```

**OR with line-break**

```
$ cat mylog
foo function1 para1=abc para2=def para3=ghi bar
foo function2 para1=jkl para2=mno para3=pqr bar
```

**Output**

```
$ awk -F'[ =]' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i=="foo")print $(i+1),$(i+5) }' mylog
function1 def
function2 mno
```

If in case your `para2` is not in order you may use this

```
$ awk -F'[ =]' '{f=""; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i=="foo")f=$(i+1); if(f && $i=="para2")print f,$(i+1)}}' mylog
```

**This is how awk see fields in record with `-F'[ =]'`**

> ```
>  With -F'[ =]' awk would see fields in record like below
>
>  foo function1 para1=abc para2=def para3=ghi bar
>   ^   ^         ^     ^   ^     ^
>   1   2         3     4   5     6
>   i  (i+1)                     (i+5)
> ```

**Explanation**

```
 awk -F'[ =]' ' # Set field separator space and =
              { 
               # Loop through no of fields in record,
               # NF gives no of fields in current record

               for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)

                   # If field equal to foo then
                   if($i=="foo")
                             # print next(i+1) and 5th(i+5) field from current field index
                             print $(i+1),$(i+5) 
              }
             ' mylog       # input file
```

**if your real input is something else, please post input and expected output**